# Grammar: Grouping comparators

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4, lexical-analysis, bnf

I have written the following grammar:

Parser:

```
comparisons: (EQUALS | (GREATER EQUALS) | (LESS EQUALS) | LESS | GREATER);
```

Lexer:

```
EQUALS: '=';
GREATER: '>';
LESS : '<';
```

However ANTLR4 is warning me that I could create a set of tokens for the comparisons. I am thinking that the parser is better suited for this as opposed to the lexer since the parser could be able to figure out:

```
1. > =  (with spaces in between)
2. > a = (error as theres a identifier in the way)
```

Could you share your ideas as to where you would put the comparisons?

Comment: On the contrary, the lexer will simply not recognize `> =` or `> a =` as single tokens (they will be recognized as two or three tokens, respectively), while the parser cannot distinguish between `> =` and `>=`

Comment: 1. is very uncommon in programming languages, 2. will be also an error, even if you use lexer rules for '>','=' and '>='. Yet I think it is not wise to put the or into a lexer rule, only one rule for each operator.